# flashScrollIndicators not working iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I am working on app in which I need to show scroll indicator in text view if lines are more than 4, but this working fine on below iOS 7 and show scroll indicator for few time but then gets hide. But but and but this not work on iOS 7. I don't know why this happen. Kindly help me on this. Here is my line of code:

```
[self.dragDropAnswerViewBody2 flashScrollIndicators];
```

`dragDropAnswerViewBody2` is a text view.

Kindly help me on this.

**Edited:**

```
if (MyDelegate.isIos7)
{
    CGRect frame=self.dragDropAnswerViewBody2.frame;
    frame.size.height= 54;
    self.dragDropAnswerViewBody2.frame=frame;
}

 [self.dragDropAnswerViewBody2 flashScrollIndicators];
```

Comment: Can you give more details? Only 1 line of code can't help much.

Comment: Actually I just used 1 line to show indicator which is working fine on iOS 7 below, but I updated question you can see code below edited.

Answer (score 2):

After some hit and try, I found the solution.
This line of code `[self.dragDropAnswerViewBody2 flashScrollIndicators];` show scroll indicator on all iOS version but what is happening actually I am loading main view animatedly where `self.dragDropAnswerViewBody2` is adding so in iOS 7 i think its taking time to load and couldn't see scroll indicator after view completely loaded, but I don't know this reason because same code works fine on before iOS 7 versions. Now I added block into animation and adding flash scroll indicator after when view completely loaded.
Below is code how I am able to do this.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.9/2 animations:^{
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self.dragDropAnswerViewBody2 flashScrollIndicators];
    }];
```

Thanks for feedback.